# Using JOptionPane Dialog in XPages Project

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I am new to using java for XPages development, I want to know if its posible to use JOptionPane Dialog in XPages Project? if yes how? or can i display a dialog component with Java. i tried the below code but notting happened

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOptionPaneMultiInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     JTextField username = new JTextField();
     JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
     Object[] message = {
       "Username test:", username,
       "Password:", password
     };

    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Login",      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

   }

}
```

I would like to use Java to display a dialog and save retured value in a variable

Comment: The second argument `message` is the Object to display. To get username and password JOptionPane is not a option, try to use JDialog.

Comment: yes but still dont display using it with XPages any idea how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is not compatible with XPages. XPages is built on JSF and I don't believe any JSF framework supports Swing.  Swing is not used for web clients, it is only used for thick clients like Windows or Mac.  Xpages is made for presenting to a web browser.

Note: JOptionPane is a part of the Swing framework. You can see this in your import which likely looks like this: `javax.swing.*;`

---

UPDATE:
You can definitely accomplish what you are asking. XPages is very feature packed and a great way to develop web applications.  It does have a fairly steep learning curve, but thankfully there are already many great free resources out there. I would start with these two:

- TLCC has a free introductory to XPages http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/free-xpages-training I also recommend their other paid courses which are very well done.
- Notes in 9, (http://www.notesin9.com/) which is a series of free how to videos.  Start with the hour long Intro to XPages: http://xpages.tv/xtv3.nsf/allEpisodes.xsp# which is where it all started to click with me.

Comment: Thanks for the information, is there any way i could display info or error message to the user, from within my java code?

Comment: is it posible for me to call the dialog component from my java code

Comment: Yes, you can call dialogs in XPages. I will modify my answer above with suggestions.

Comment: yes but i want to call dialog component from java class, is that posible?

Comment: You would need to launch the dialog from an XPage or custom control.  Maybe you should closeout this question and create a new one asking what you want to do and *why* and see if others can offer you suggestions/alternatives.